# jar file can't translate bangla unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, jar

I am having some problems while running a .jar file of a Java Application we have developed. The application transliterates some Bangla proper nouns to English. There are some input files for the application which provide unicode numbers of the Bangla characters. When I run the application in Netbeans 8.0.2 the program outputs okay. It can successfully converts Bangla characters to English ones. But after creating a .jar file when I try to run the .jar file it cannot output English characters. Rather it shows some characters like these:

[image]

I think the problem is not in the code as it is running okay from netbeans. Now what's the problem? Can't the .jar file read the input files? I searched over internet for finding solutions. Some suggest about META-INF folder, some suggest about getresourceasstream() function. But I can't solve the problem by any of the processes. Can anyone give me a better suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's more likely that you will get a good answer if, to the extent it's possible, you can post code for a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Comment: if it works with Netbeans and not from jar, problem may be in char-encoding.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding